# How Skip a wep page before the blog page,which blog page  i have to parse?

Tags: parsing, web

i have a parser which parse a blog page which is parsing others page fine, instead One page and that page opens the Protection Page which ask the user to Wish to continue or not, because that blog page have some Adult content . So my parser failed at that time when that Protection page comes.Any idea to how i solve this issue.?
    Thank you  in Advance !!!

Here is the Image-[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the protection system is designed. If it is a mere redirection, you can skip the page. However, if it works by setting a cookie, you will have to visit the page, receive the cookie, and then pass that cookie back.

Are you parsing using `cURL` or something else?

Comment: i have only that blog URl even i have that image,i am uploading that image too.Thanks For Replying.

Comment: You'll have to analyze how that works. Use your browser console or a tool like Fiddler to check if a cookie is being set when you click on 'I Understand...'